# Webhosting in a 6in4 tunnel, allow ipv4 access (NON-DUALSTACK)

Tags: proxy, web-hosting, ipv6, tunnel

I'm serving a website with a 6in4 tunnel using gogo6client.
It is accessible over ipv6 native clients, but not ipv4.
For network setup reasons I cannot forward port 80 in NAT on the ipv4 side of things.
I was wondering if there was a way to translate or proxy inbound ipv4 traffic to see my ipv6 site.

maybe something that routes ipv4 clients to a 6in4 tunnel as well, but on the fly, without installing a client.

I know this site ( ipv6proxy.prolocation.net ) enables ipv4 websites access to the ipv6 network, however what I am asking is the reverse.
Is this possible?

-td8f4